# Whether to use an article with certain nouns

Tags: article

I want to ask a question about whether to use an article (Ein/Eine/Der/Die/Das)
with weapons and such.

The abbreviations used in my question:

- [Rutschnoi Protiwotankowy Granatomjot (RPG)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPG_(Waffe))
- [RIFLE 5.56-MM, M16](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M16_(Gewehr))

Do we say: Das ist ein RPG / das ist ein M16.
or do we suffice with: Das ist RPG / Das ist M16.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Könntest du dir die Mühe machen, die Frage zu lesen, bevor Downvote und Closevote kommen?

Comment: @DavidVogt Und das ändert an der Qualität der Frage was genau? Ich habe das gelesen, und ich bezweifle das hier eine vernünftige Antworrt gegeben werden kann.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of abbreviations, the article refers to the basic word. e.g. **die** Granate and **der** Werfer becomes **der** Granatwerfer. Therefore **der** is to be used for RPG from **der** Granatwerfer and **das** for M16 form **das** Gewehr.

> - Der RPG ist ein tragbarer Panzerabwehr-Granatwerfer, der von Hand gehalten wird.
> - Das M16 wurde 1967 als Gewehr der US-Streitkräfte eingeführt.

English:

> - The RPG is a hand-held portable anti-tank grenade launcher.
> - The M16 was introduced in 1967 as rifle of the US Armed Forces.

The original Russian translation leads to "**der** Granatwerfer", because the later English translation *Rocket Propelled Grenade (**die** raketenangetriebene Granate* does not technically cover all variants.

As mentioned in your question above following is OK for a short use:

> - Das ist ein RPG. ... Das ist ein Granatwerfer.
> - Das ist ein M16. ... Das ist ein Gewehr.

Comment: Are you sure? Wikipedia agrees with you regarding the "M16" (neuter) but treats the "RPG" as feminine. See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M16_(Gewehr), https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPG_(Waffe). Not sure if that reflects the broader use, just thought I'd point it out as it doesn't comport with this answer.

Comment: Do you have a source or a reasoning, *why* these articles should be set? This might help learners to understand the underlying rules or to learn where to look up such things.

Comment: @johnl and Arsak - thanks for the hint. It seems to me the article *die* used for RPG on Wikipedia is derived from *die* **Granate**. This is wrong for **Granatwerfer** as mentioned in my EDIT.

Comment: I agree with you that the article has to be used and it refers to the orginal word. The only little detail is wether RPG is a "Granatwerfer" (der) or a "Granate" (die).

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can regard (some) weapon names as proper nouns, such as the AK-47 or the M4A1, you still have to use an article - the female one, to be precise. This is valid for pistols, assault/sniper rifles, machine pistols and machine guns. I would address the RPG with a neutral article, or with a male article in case of RPG-launcher.
Unfortunately I can only provide you my native instinct and couldn't find a credible source. Still, there are some examples found on [Dayz-Duden.de.tl](https://dayz-duden.de.tl/Sturmgewehre.htm), which I'll link here just for the pun.